# Macros invisible to excel, but can be run from ribbon if already established, and appear in VBA editor

Tags: excel, vba

I have some macros attached to buttons in the Quick Access Ribbon. All but one of the buttons have been functioning normally, so I'm not sure when this started.

I tried to use a less-used macro button this morning called `Unhide All Sheets` and it threw this error:

> Cannot run the macro 'PERSONAL.XLSB!UnhideAllSheets.UnhideAllSheets'.  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be deleted."

So I went to review my code and all my macros are invisible from the front-end. I select `Developer -> Macros`, the list is completely empty, and when I attempt to create new buttons on the Quick Access Toolbar, the macro list there is also completely empty.

When I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VBA editor, I can see and update macros in specific workbooks and in my personal workbook.  Most of them still run, although the offending macro (UnhideAllSheets) throws an `Unexpected Error (35005)` when run from the editor.

Anybody ever seen this before?  I've been googling for an hour with no results.

**Most Macro Buttons still work**
[image]

**Nothing on the Macro List**
[image]

**Customize Ribbon can't see the macros**
[image]

**Still visible and functioning in VBA Editor (except for "UnhideAllSheets")**
[image]

Comment: So, `Personal.xlsb` workbook is open. Does it have a module named `UnhideAllSheets` and inside it a `Sub` named `UnhideAllSheets`? If yes, try repairing Office installation.

Comment: `throws an "Unexpected Error (35005)" when run from the editor....` I could be wrong but I am guessing that your file is corrupt. Try this **1.** Click File > Open. **2.** In the Open dialog box, select the corrupted workbook. **3.** Click the arrow next to the Open button, and then click Open and Repair. See if that helped? **IMP NOTE**: Create a backup of the file before you attempt the repair

Comment: @FaneDuru - Repair did the job.  I figured that was my next course of action but didn't want to break things further without doing some research with the whiz kids.  Thank you for the fast response.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - This was a problem with everything I opened in excel, rather than a single file, and there was no evidence of file corruption being the root cause, but I appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I manually checked/marked **atpvbaen** in the tools>references. This has solved my problem !

[image: Tools> references]
[image: select and check]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue, where some buttons were working and some weren't. What I noticed was my module's name was similar to my procedure's (macro's) name. I'm not aware of the reason, but I when ensured procedures names' are different than the module names.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I manually checked/marked alt 2.0 Type Library in the tools>references. This has solved my problem !